# Почему исчезают блоки wordpress

Tags: wordpress

На сайте установлена своя тема. Сайт http://bfkk03.tmweb.ru

когда появляется запись, например новости, они отображаются на главной(сейчас новостей нет) тут же исчезают правый сайдбар и футер.
Можно посмотреть на странице Документы во вкладке Сведения ...

Пробывал отключать плагины, редактировал functions
На локальном хостинге все работает.Как это исправить?

Comment: У вас там ошибка jQuery: "scripts.js?ver=15.9.8:35 Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).live is not a function". Возможно, из-за того, что не выполняются скрипты после ошибки.

Comment: Но вообще-то вряд ли. Сравнил html на двух страницах - похоже на то, что php вылетает по ошибке после формирования центрального блока  (новости, документы)